# How to detect the USB drive is NTFS or FAT32 in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

When the user plug in new USB drive, is there a way to detect whether this drive is NTFS or FAT32 in objective-c. If possible could you show me a simple demo?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NSWorkspace`'s `-getFileSystemInfoForPath:isRemovable:isWritable:isUnmountable:description:type:` selector to get the filesystem (as well as the other listed attributes).

Check out Apple's [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/getFileSystemInfoForPath%3aisRemovable%3aisWritable%3aisUnmountable%3adescription%3atype%3a). All the parameters except `fullPath` are out parameters (fullPath is the filesystem's mount point), so the values of the variables will be changed. The `path:` parameter is the one that'll return a string containing the name of the filesystem type.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you really care if it's NTFS or FAT32?  I don't see a way to easily do that.  If you care about whether the volume is writable or not, that looks to be doable.

First, you can get a list of mounted volumes with the NSFileManager method:

```
– mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys:options:
```

You will get an NSArray of NSURL objects.  With the NSURL you can use a method like:

```
– resourceValuesForKeys:error:
```

There are various Volume Information keys in there.  For example, "NSURLVolumeIsReadOnlyKey".

Comment: Probably because both have different limitations/constraints.